# Java error using JARs, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Store

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I'm making a java application that uses Javamail, and it works great when I compile it. I want to make it into a jar file so it can be easily moved around and executed. The problem is I am getting this error when I try to run the jar from the cmd line

java -jar ActriveTray2.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Store
        at stockApp.init(stockApp.java:11)
        at ActiveTray.main(ActiveTray.java:31)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Store
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here's what's in my jar file

- images/tray.gif
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- ActiveTray.class
- ActiveTray.java
- config.class
- config.java
- GmailFetch.class
- GmailFetch.java
- stockApp$1.class
- stockApp.class
- stockApp.java

I think the issue is classpath, where the jar doesn't know where the javamail jar lives. My classpath is set correctly when I execute the code (java ActiveTray2) it works fine... help :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to add the jars you depend on to the manifest file, and also add them to the jar you are creating. java -jar will ignore your environment's classpath, by design.
[From the java docs:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> -jar: When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

so, you can add a line to your manifest file like:

```
Class-Path: mail.jar
```

to your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I don't know how to update my manifest file to do that. I added Class-Path: mail.jar to my manifest, but it's still not working...

Comment: Ofcourse the jar has to be in the right place too when you run your application.

Comment: So do I add mail.jar to my own jar? I just don't know how to reference it so the classpath is correct? And I've googled this for an hour...

Comment: rob, in my example above, the mail.jar would need to be in the "root" of your jar. you could also put it in a directory, but you would then need to specify that directory in the Class-Path directive of the manifest.

Comment: rob, when you jar -tvf myjar.jar, do you see lib/mail.jar?

Comment: so you've got lib/mail.jar in your manifest, and you see lib/mail.jar in the jar you're creating, and you are positive that lib/mail.jar contains javax.mail.Store?

Comment: not positive on the last part... will look. The code compiles fine when i run it from cmd line, just when i jar it, the classpath gets funky

Comment: Add directory structure of your project and path to mail.jar to your question. Maybe you are tired and simply mixed up something.

Comment: images/tray.gif
lib/activation.jar
lib/mail.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ActiveTray.class
ActiveTray.java
config.class
config.java
GmailFetch.class
GmailFetch.java
stockApp$1.class
stockApp.class
stockApp.java

Comment: and this is my manifest
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/mail.jar
Created-By: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: ActiveTray

Comment: rob, it should really be working. can you verify mail.jar contains the class it's complaining about? you can grep for it. as a last ditch effort, you can try moving it out of lib and to the root. in your main class, you can system.out.println the classpath it's using, and see if mail.jar is present

Comment: Hi Paul, I opened mail.jar and I see the Store class so it exists. Stil not working... the Class-Path line in the manifest, it's allowed to be lib/mail.jar right? or lib.mail.jar?

Comment: Hi Paul, can I send you my code to see if you can get it to work? I'm still getting the error....

Comment: i got it working! - kinda. I put the mail.jar and activation.jar in the same folder as my test.jar and it worked? I updated my manifest to just use mail.jar activation.jar instead of lib/mail.jar. I think I get this now. will advise when it is working perfectly

Comment: as in the dependent jar resources (mail.jar etc) do not live in my own jar, they get sent along with it, and could live in a lib folder to keep things tidy.... my mistake was putting them in my jar, in a folder called lib....

Comment: yes! it worked. wow, I made a mountain out of a molehill on this one... so now i know, any extra jar files live outside my own jar (not included in it)... thanks Paul for all your help

Answer (score 1):

When you launch a runnable jar file in java, the classpath is ignored, both the environment variable and the command line classpath. You have to specify it inside the manifest file of your runnable jar file.

Here is some information from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_of_a_Jar_file) :

You manifest has to include :

```
Main-Class: org.mypackage.HelloWorld
Class-Path: lib/supportLib.jar
<additional line feed and carriage return>
```

The class-path will list the location of the librairies you use *relative to the location of your main runnable jar file*.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

The required mail implementation jars should be present in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i faced in my project. The reason is jar file missing or not locate in class path. Two steps to solve this issue.

1. First add [JavaMail API 1.4.7 jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR) to the class path.
2. Then add the same jar to server library. In my application i used Apache tomcat 7. i put the jar in **lib** folder